# Как вычислить равномерное увеличение сложной 3D фигуры

Tags: 3d, геометрия, объекты, three.js, формулы

Добрый день, есть некий абстрактный 3D объект сложной геометрии.
Скажем его объем V₁ кубических метра.

Задача расчитать величину (на иллюстрации выделена желтым) на которую надо сместить каждую вершину объекта, чтобы в результате получился объект с новым объемом V₂.

Есть ли какая-нибудь формула для нахождения этой величины? 
В английском сегменте данная операция называется offset.

[image]

Comment: +1 за хорошую иллюстрацию к вопросу

Comment: Тут, скорее всего, речь не про offset, а про scale. Как мне видится: var scale = V2 / V1;

Comment: @VVK - "расчитать величину" - вектор?

Comment: Это не scale. При scale — стороны увеличиваются пропорционально.
Скажем если взять 2D пространство и прямоугольник скажем 10 на 20, то его масштабирование на 150% это 15 х 30, а offset скажем на 2.5 дает 15 х 35.

Comment: Прямоугольник - это частный случай, и при этом очень идеальный, так как полигон выпуклый. Равно как и параллелепипед - тоже выпуклое тело. На рисунке - тело ни разу не выпуклое.

Comment: Прямоугольник дан исключительно для иллюстрации.

Comment: Скорее всего для сложных фигур такой расчет невозможен и надо просто брут форсом подбирать с заданной погрешностью, но хотелось бы вначале проконсультироваться.

Comment: @VVK Вы находитесь на пути, ведущему к созданию самопересекающихся трехмерных фигур и к неправильному вычислению их объема.

Comment: 1. То что они могут пересекаться не входило в условие задачи. Могут. Визуальные артефакты имеются. 2. Мне не надо вычислять объем. Точнее надо только для оригинала. Второй объем задан.

Comment: К слову, о смещении по нормалям вершин, самопересечении и подобии объектов [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/9cfaj526/)

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer:* с `three.js` не работал.

Для каждой вершины новое положение:

```
(kx, ky, kz). где

k = кубический_корень_из(V2/V1)
```

То есть координаты каждой вершины надо изменить на

```
((k - 1)x, (k - 1)y, (k - 1)z)
```

А потом сдвиньте все координаты, чтобы, например, центры тяжести старой и новой фигуры совпадали, или описывающий параллелепипед равномерно расширился/сжался в направлениях координатных осей.

Но это уже зависит от дополнительных условий задачи, не включенных в вопрос.

*Такое не должно пропасть. Сохраним для истории.*

> Если для 2D такая же формула, но только с квадратным корнем, то она не
>   работает. Если конечно правильно считал. Тот же прямоугольник 10x20.
>   Площадь его 200 единиц. Хотим увеличить до 300. корень квадратный (300
>   / 200 ) = 1.224745... Если его применяем к сторонам, то у полученной
>   фигуры площадь 279.5
>
> Для 10х20 до 300, величина должна быть что-то около 1.51
>
> А разве корень квадратный из 1.5 (300/200) не 1.224745? Остальное я не
>   считал, а строил в Rhinoceros3D.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59824/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------3d-).